# iframes download font file again though it is downloaded in main doc

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fonts

I have main html file and one iframe tag in that. iframe contains whole another #document with all  and  tag.

In body tag there are divs which uses fonts that downloaded when loading of the main document started. when i try to open the document of the iframe, in chrome, required font file is again downloads for the document inside the iframe.

i dont want to download the font file for the iframe doc instead of using the same font file which is downloaded at the start of the main doc(if present). If required font is not dowloaded by the main document then only download the font file.

If any server related changes requiered then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected but from my knowledge the iframe will need to download the fonts as the iframe makes its own requests and doesn't inherit any styles from the parent page (your main page).

Hope this helps.

Comment: But in other browsers like mozzila and ie10 those resources are already loaded in iframe when iframe loaded in the dom. There is no need to download it again of those resources in above browsers. Even when i load my site from the IIS server this issue get fixed, iframe loaded those required resources at loading of the main documnet only.

Comment: Hope you understand my question.

Comment: Your document loaded within the iframe is still a document of it’s own, and behaves like any other document, whether it be displayed in a frame or not, when it comes to making requests it will have to call it's own styles, scripts etc. Also, could you put your code up on http://jsfiddle.net/ if you'd like for me to have a look at it